# JMeter Scenario Creation

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have a Payload where I need to run for one hour with Spike in between. After starting the test, first 20 mins threads need to be in idle state and then One minute spike with some 50 tps and again 10 minutes idle and spike with same payload again for 1 minute. Which thread group, controllers and timers are best suite for the same.

1 hr test with below criteria

0 to 20 min ---- Idle
1 Min (60 sec) --- 50 tps
21  to 30 -- Idle again
30 to 31 (1 min) -- spike again with 90 tps this time
31 to 40 --- idle again
40-41 min -- Spike again with 120 tps
41 - 60 - idle again

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options, the easiest would be [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) combination

[image]

By the way given this 20 minutes "idle" period you can just skip it, as long as JMeter will not be sending any requests you can launch your test after 20 minutes from the start date and save the electricity and trees.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried up to here. Due to 0 RPS, threads are going to sleeping mode and never coming back again. 

How to set start date and time and electricity tree. Appreciate your help. 

Please note that I need to implement the same as part same text